# Document seems to be null but I can get the first element

Tags: java, xml, dom

I build a DOM document with this Code:

```
private org.w3c.dom.Document createXml(WorkObject workObject, String hierarchy, String dateFormat) {
    XMLBuilder2 builder = XMLBuilder2.create(hierarchy);
    Map<String, Object> localVariables = workObject.getLocalVariablesMap();
    builder = createXmlFromMap(localVariables, builder, dateFormat);
    Properties outputProperties = new Properties();
    outputProperties.put(javax.xml.transform.OutputKeys.OMIT_XML_DECLARATION, "no");
    String xmlString = builder.asString(outputProperties);
    LOG.debug("XML string: " + xmlString);
    org.w3c.dom.Document xmlDoc = builder.getDocument();
    LOG.debug("DOM root element: " + xmlDoc.getDocumentElement().getTagName());
    return xmlDoc;
}
```

the `builder.asString()`call returns the expected XML:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<root>
    <myVar>a value</myVar>
    <docId>GEAR-b3384419-36f8-48fc-b194-c937e7afc0dd</docId>
</root>
```

The output of the last LOG statement is `root` as expected.

But when I use this code, the `xmlDoc` seems to be something weird...

when passing the `xmlDoc` to this constructor:

```
private org.w3c.dom.Document mXmlDoc;

public XmlMailMergeDataSet(org.w3c.dom.Document xmlDoc) {
    mXmlDoc = xmlDoc;
}
```

When debugging in IDEA, the value of `xmlDoc` and `mXmlDoc` then is `[#document: null]`

Unfortunaly, I can not debug further to see what happens then since the code where the XmlMailMergeDataSet then is passed to is not open source.

Am I missing something obvious here?

Answer (score 1):

`[#document: null]` doesn't mean the `Document` reference is null, nor that the tree is empty. It is just the string representation as a result of evaluating `xmlDoc.toString())`. I guess the `null` here is the "node value" of the document node which in this case has no meaning (`Document` is a special subtype of `Node`).

So the `Document` instance does not seem to have any issue in your code.

Comment: Thanks for this clarification. This is good in one way: My code seems ok, but bad in the other: My problem seems to be in that part of the code I can't debug.